# How do I get a description in my Google knowledge panel?

Tags: seo, google

If I search google for the phrase "rgraph about" I get the little boxout pictured below. Whilst this has my logo - how would I go about adding a description too?

[image: A screenshot of Google search results]

Answer (score 1):

The **[Google Knowledge Graph Search API](https://developers.google.com/knowledge-graph/)** informs us:

> The Knowledge Graph Search API lets you find entities in the **[Google Knowledge Graph](https://www.google.com/intl/bn/search/about/)**. The API uses standard schema.org types and is compliant with the **[JSON-LD](https://json-ld.org/)** specification.

So, will it be useful for you to use structured data on your website for the best presentation your business or your as person in Google knowledge panel.

Further, the above guide Google reports a list of object types that can be supported by the Knowledge Graph:

> - **[Book](https://schema.org/Book)**
> - **[BookSeries](https://schema.org/BookSeries)**
> - **[EducationalOrganization](https://schema.org/EducationalOrganization)**
> - **[Event](https://schema.org/Event)**
> - **[GovernmentOrganization](https://schema.org/GovernmentOrganization)**
> - **[LocalBusiness](https://schema.org/LocalBusiness)**
> - **[Movie](https://schema.org/Movie)**
> - **[MovieSeries](https://schema.org/MovieSeries)**
> - **[MusicAlbum](https://schema.org/MusicAlbum)**
> - **[MusicGroup](https://schema.org/MusicGroup)**
> - **[MusicRecording](https://schema.org/MusicRecording)**
> - **[Organization](https://schema.org/Organization)**
> - **[Periodical](https://schema.org/Periodical)**
> - **[Person](https://schema.org/Person)**
> - **[Place](https://schema.org/Place)**
> - **[SportsTeam](https://schema.org/SportsTeam)**
> - **[TVEpisode](https://schema.org/TVEpisode)**
> - **[TVSeries](https://schema.org/TVSeries)**
> - **[VideoGame](https://schema.org/VideoGame)**
> - **[VideoGameSeries](https://schema.org/VideoGameSeries)**
> - **[WebSite](https://schema.org/WebSite)**

Choose and apply the types that most fully can represent the main content of each separate of your web pages. Read more **[Structured Data General Guidelines](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/sd-policies)**.

To represent your logo in the Google Knowledge Graph, refer to the **[Guide of Google for Logos](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/logo)**.

Here you can focus your attention on the requirement for the property **[logo](https://schema.org/logo)**:

> Additional image guidelines:
>
> - **The image must be 112x112px, at minimum**.
> - The image URL must be crawlable and indexable.
> - The image must be in .jpg, .png, or. gif format.

So the logo of your organization should be square. I recommend to use this property with the embed type **[ImageObject](https://schema.org/ImageObject)** that is more detailed structuring your logo.

Comment: I've got the logo, though I've read elsewhere that Google takes the description from WikiPedia. And since I don't have a WikiPedia entry - no description... :-(

Comment: Well this guide Google gives conflicting recommendations https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35624